# How to cycle through Textbox Controls Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I wanted a code that would cycle thru the names of text box controls on a form whose `Visible` = true.  I know this code is constructed incorrectly, but I need to ask if anyone can point me in the right direction.

```
Public Sub TxtBoxNamevisible(ByRef pfrm As Form)
Dim ctl As Control
Dim txtbx As TextBox

For Each txtbx In pfrm.Controls.visible = true
MsgBox txtbx.Name
Next txtbx
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pfrm.Controls.visible` does not compile because `Controls` is a collection. `Visible` is a supported property for members of that collection, but not supported on the collection itself.

Loop through `pfrm.Controls`, check whether each of them is a `Visible` text box, and `MsgBox` the names of those which are ...

```vb
Dim ctl As Control
For Each ctl In pfrm.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acTextBox And ctl.Visible = True Then
        MsgBox ctl.Name
    End If
Next ctl
```

Comment: HansUp, thanxs so much.  I'm sincerely grateful for your help.